# How to trigger graphql useQuery on demand only once?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-component, apollo-client, vue-composition-api

With the help of [graphql-codegenerator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-vue-apollo) we created a graphql `useQuery` that correctly retrieves data from the backend. When a string is entered into an input field the function `driverRule` is called to verify the input, which in turn should call the `useQuery` only once.

#### Problem

However, when we `enable` the query with the `ref` useQuery is immediately executed, a second execution is invoked with the `refetch()` method. All subsequent calls to `driverRule` will only invoke useQuery once as desired. But the very first call does it twice which is not desired.

```js
import {computed, defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useSapTruckRosterDriverQuery } from 'src/graphql/generated/operations'

export default defineComponent({
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const showTruckId = ref(false)
    const driverId = computed(() => (!showTruckId.value ? answer.value : ''))
    const queryEnabled = ref<'driver' | 'truck'>()

    const { refetch: getDriverQuery } = useSapTruckRosterDriverQuery(
      () => ({ id: driverId.value }),
      () => ({ enabled: queryEnabled.value === 'driver' })
    )

    const driverRule = async (value: string) => {
      queryEnabled.value = 'driver'

      const result = await getDriverQuery({ id: value })

      if (result.data.driver.__typename === 'DriverArray') {
        return result.data.driver.data?.length ? true : 'Truck not found'
      }
    }
```

#### What we tried:

- Move `useQuery` within the `driverRule` function but this yields the following error:

> [Vue warn]: onServerPrefetch is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup().

- useQuery with option `emabled: false` and only `refetch()` in `driverRule`. This does not execute useQuery at all

#### Workaround

Accept the default behavior and enable the query by default with a static variable value and not use the result from the first run but only the one from `refetch()`. This still results in 2 calls to the backend though, but it can't be avoided.

```js
    const { refetch: getDriverQuery } = useSapTruckRosterDriverQuery(
      { id: 'initialQueryActivationCall' }
    )

    const driverRule = async (value: string) => {
      const result = await getDriverQuery({ id: value })
      if (result.data.driver.__typename === 'DriverArray') {
        return result.data.driver.data?.length ? true : 'Truck not found'
      }
    }
```

#### Question

It seems really hard to just call `useQuery` only once when the function `driverRule` is called. How can we avoid having 2 calls when only 1 call is needed to the backend?

Comment: Did you look in to [`useLazyQuery`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually)?  It lets you dictate when the query should be fired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **useApolloClient** from @vue/apollo-composable package.

```
//other imports...
import { useApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { gql } from '@apollo/client/core'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const { client } = useApolloClient()

        const GET_DOGS = gql`
            query GetDogs {
                dogs {
                   id
                   breed
                }
            }
        `;

        const getDogs = async (): Promise<void> => {
            const { data, } = await client.query({
                query: GET_DOGS
            })
        }

        return {
            getDogs,
        }
    },
})
```